# Select Item on Spinner

Tags: java, android

I want to ask for help.

I already created a list of activities in Android Studio. 
Each Activity contains a specific item. Those items are different "Departments" in our University.

Example:

> Activity 1 = College of Computer Studies;
>
> Activity 2 = College of Teacher Education;
>
> Activity 3 = College of Engineering.

My Spinner contains the departments.

My problem is, if I choose "College in Computer Science" in Spinner and click the "SEND" button, I want Activity 1 to be shown.

Would you help me with the code to do that?

**Spinner in activity_main.xml

```
<Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spin"
        android:entries="@array/punpDepartments"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
    </Spinner>
```

**These are the items in strings.xml

```
<string-array name="punpDepartments">
        <item>College of Computer Studies</item>
        <item>College of Business Education</item>
        <item>College of Criminal Justice Education</item>
        <item>College of Marine Education</item>
        <item>College of Nursing</item>
        <item>College of Pharmacy</item>
        <item>College of Education</item>
```

**My code in Intent at MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static Button button_send;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OnClickButtonListener();
    }
    public void OnClickButtonListener(){
        button_send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button_send.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.imelda.mythesis.ListActivity");
            startActivity(intent);

        }
        }
        );

    }
```

**Extends in ListActivity.java

```
public class ListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static Button button_next;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    OnClickButtonListener();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list, menu);
    return true;
}
public void OnClickButtonListener() {
    button_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button_next.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.imelda.mythesis.SecondList");
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
    );
}
```

**I have also added this in AndroidManifest.xml enter code here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.imelda.mythesis" >
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />  
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.imelda.mythesis.ListActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: how you have create spinner ? add some code

Comment: have you tried creating an intent to open the new activity?

Answer (score 0):

first get your spinner in the main class like this

```
Spinner spin =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spin);
```

now in your on click method do this

```
    int position =spin.getSelectedItemPosition();
    //change the activities with yours
    switch (position){

        case 0: intent.setClass(Activity1.class,MainActivity.this);
            break;
        case 1: intent.setClass(Activity2.class,MainActivity.this);
            break;
        case 2: intent.setClass(Activity3.class,MainActivity.this);
            break;
        case 3: intent.setClass(Activity4.class,MainActivity.this);
            break;
        case 4: intent.setClass(Activity5.class,MainActivity.this);
            break;
    }
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Hello Mr. Avanash Joshi. :') I've tried this code but my app stop working. :(